# Minecraft SMP randomly teleporting to a set location

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-bukkit

I run a minecraft bukkit server, 1.7.10-r3 with a handful of plugins. There is a specific location that players get teleported to at random times, sometimes it's only once in a few hours, sometimes several times per minute. There is nothing in the server console, I dug a hole down to bedrock under this location so that when players get teleported there they die, allowing me to see when it happens exactly. There is absolutely no pattern whatsoever as to when this happens and it's extremely annoying. Any ideas?

Comment: What are the coordinates of the specific location? What plugins are you using? Do you have command blocks turned on? You could try turning the plugins off one a time (or do a binary-search type thing) to narrow it down and find which one is causing the issue (or if it's vanilla).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone else has this problem, I had a command block set to silently teleport people to that location. I dug out around where it was and confirmed there was no way it could be activated. People continued to get teleported anyways, but breaking the command block fixed the problem.

I never figured out what was setting it off.